# Laravel 8 Javascript function not working with form tag

Tags: javascript, html

The code below works fine without the use of the **FORM** tag.

But after I add the **FORM** tag, the code does not work anymore.

**My code:**

```js
function ismcstop() {
  var chkNo = document.getElementById("radio2_ismcstop");
  var mcnostopreason = document.getElementById("mcnostopreason");
  mcnostopreason.disabled = chkNo.checked ? false : true;
  if (!mcnostopreason.disabled) {
    mcnostopreason.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="container">
        <label for="ismcstop">Machine Stop?</label>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1_ismcstop">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1_ismcstop" name="ismcstop" onclick="ismcstop()" value="Yes">Yes
              </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2_ismcstop">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2_ismcstop" name="ismcstop" onclick="ismcstop()" value="No">No
              </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <label for="mcnostopreason">If No, Reason:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <input class="inputstyle-100" id="mcnostopreason" name="" value="" disabled>
    </div>
  </div><br>

</form>
```

Comment: Just rename your ismcstop() function name!

Comment: What do u mean ?

Comment: change ``function ismcstop()`` to some other name like ``function ismcstopfn()``

Comment: How renaming the function solve the problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just rename `ismcstop()` function name like below

```js
function ismcsfortop() {
        var chkNo = document.getElementById("radio2_ismcstop");
        var mcnostopreason = document.getElementById("mcnostopreason");
        mcnostopreason.disabled = chkNo.checked ? false : true;
        if (!mcnostopreason.disabled) {
            mcnostopreason.focus();
        }
    }
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="container">
        <label for="ismcstop">Machine Stop?</label>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1_ismcstop">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1_ismcstop" name="ismcstop" onclick="ismcsfortop()" value="Yes">Yes
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2_ismcstop">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2_ismcstop" name="ismcstop" onclick="ismcsfortop()" value="No">No
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <label for="mcnostopreason">If No, Reason:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <input class="inputstyle-100" id="mcnostopreason" name="" value="" disabled>
    </div>
  </div><br>

</form>
```

Comment: Wow its work.
Wait.. How on earth renaming the function solve this problem ?

Comment: @siddharth Providing an answer with working code is good. Providing details about why it works, what you changed and why is much better.

Comment: Because it is conflicted, once change name it resoled, JS is very delicate about naming conventions so we have to try to make every name unique.

Comment: What conflicts with what? Your explanation is very unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Change the name of the label to something else other than ismcstop. I think it is overridden the function.

```
    <label for="ismcstopLabel">Machine Stop?</label>
```

OR

Change the function name ismcstop() to ismcstopFunc()

Comment: How renaming the function solve the problem ?